# Test autocomplete in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a search form which would open a list when 2 characters are typed. I would like to measure that time it takes to open and load the list in jmeter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you look into your "Network" tab of your favourite browser developer tools you will see that each time you type a letter or digit in the search field the browser sends a HTTP request to the backend server and it responds with search suggestions:

[image: JMeter Google Search Suggestions]

So all you need to do is to simulate these requests using JMeter and measure the response time.

You can even record these requests using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/), [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), whatever

[image: JMeter HTTPS Test Script Recorder Autocomplete]

Answer (score -2):

There are two things, I would like to quote:

### JMeter is not a browser

> [JMeter is not a browser](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it works at protocol level. As far as
> web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a
> browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not
> perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter
> does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it
> render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the
> response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any
> samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a
> time).

### [From JMeter Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#Does_JMeter_process_dynamic_pages_.28e.g._Javascript_and_applets.29)

> **JMeter does not process Javascript** or applets embedded in HTML pages.
>
> JMeter can download the relevant resources (some embedded resources
> are downloaded automatically if the correct options are set), but it
> does not process the HTML and execute any Javascript functions.
>
> If the page uses Javascript to build up a URL or submit a form, you
> can use the Proxy Recording facility to create the necessary sampler.
> If this is not possible, then manual inspection of the code may be
> needed to determine what the Javascript is doing.

### Solution #1

Whenever you type each character, check any service call to the server. This can be captured using **browser developer tools > Network** tab.

E.g.

If you type `iPhone`, there will be six service calls to the server. By measuring each call individually, you will be able to understand, how your application behaves under the load.

Again this is a service call, not the UI rendering.

`https://example.com?q=i`

`https://example.com?q=iP`

`https://example.com?q=iPh`

`https://example.com?q=iPho`

`https://example.com?q=iPhon`

`https://example.com?q=iPhone`

### Solution #2

By leveraging **Selenium WebDriver** in your **JMeter Test plan**, you can measure the end-to-end response time.

Please refer this [Blazemeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) and [this blog](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/) for more details.

Visit [JMeter Plugins website](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and search for **Selenium** to read more details about Selenium WebDriver.